# file-system path creation error (file upload)

Tags: php, file-upload

my code keeps on saying that the folder does not exist though it should be checked by the mkdir function..it creates the folder but does not go through the uploading process.. and displays the error on the couldnt find the folder.. is the algorithm correct? please help.. Your advice will help! :)

here is the code..

```
if(!(file_exists($target_path)))
{
    if(!mkdir($target_path, 0777, TRUE))
    {
        die ("could not create the folder on mkdir");
    }
    //in this line the error occurs..printing what is below..//
    die ("could not find folder on file exists");
}
else
{
    umask($target_path);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you quote the exact error messages and which lines they occur on?

Comment: @Pekka I already did.. please have a look.. thank you.. :D

Comment: thanks for the edit @hakre hehe.. :D dont know how to say it..

Comment: @SimonCode: I edited your question again and reduced the code to the part that plays the role here. Probably you now better see where your problem with this is. The cause of your problem is that you write many if/else clauses into each other which makes your code complex. Create functions instead that do part of the work, then invoke the functions to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_exists()` routine requires the complete path to file like

```
/var/www/uploads/file1.c
```

so the

```
file_exists($target_path);
```

call is ok . but second call to make directory, ie,

```
mkdir()
```

is requiring an directory , not an path to an file ie, it require /var/www/upload part only .
so you can remove the basename from path name and apply it to mkdir function()

Answer (score 1):

try..

**if(file_exists($target_path) && is_dir($target_path)){  //rest of the code...
  }**

instead of...

if(!(file_exists($target_path))){

}

Hope this will do something for you...

...............................

one thing more...
i think the problem is with **if(!(file_exists($target_path))){}** Statement,

THIS SHOULD BE...
**if(!file_exists($target_path)){}**

Answer (score 1):

during the file upload process, your file saving path in [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
function may be creating problem. I am saying may be because your given code is not clear enough to me. Second parameter of move_uploaded_file() is the destination where first parameter is the file name. please check the value of $target_path, it may solve your problem. thank you.